# Error in Argument with Reduced Mayer-Vietoris for Disjoint Union

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was trying to prove something and came across an apparent contradiction. I am sure there is a very basic mistake somewhere in my line of reasoning, but I can't find it and would appreciate it if someone else can.

So let $X$ and $Y$ be contractible spaces and $Z=X\sqcup Y$ their disjoint union. Now consider the reduced version of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. We have:
$$
\cdots\to\tilde{H}_0(X\cap Y)\to \tilde{H}_0(X)\oplus\tilde{H}_0(Y)\to\tilde{H}_0(Z)\to 0
$$ 
Now $X\cap Y$ is empty, and $\tilde{H}_0(X)=\tilde{H}_0(Y)=0$ because we assume $X$ and $Y$ to be contractible. But $Z$ has two components, namely $X$ and $Y$, so $\tilde{H}_0(Z)=\mathbb{Z}$.
Thus, the Mayer-Vietoris sequence is given by
$$
\cdots\to 0\to 0\to\mathbb{Z}\to 0
$$
which cannot possibly be exact. So where am I going wrong?

Comment: It is almost never correct to use reduced cohomology without a basepoint. Unfortunately some texts introduce it for nonbasepointed space, when really such a thing has few uses. The correct notion of reduced cohomology is that if $(X,x_0)$ is a pointed space, $\bar{H}_*(X)=H_* (X,x_0)$. Then if we are in the realm of pointed space, we should replace disjoint union with wedge sum. If you do this then your $Z$ will be contractible (if both are CW complexes), and all is right in the world.

Comment: If I had to guess what the actual error in your post is, it probably is that for this version of reduced homology, you are required to have your spaces intersect (this is really just a mask for the fact that in "real" reduced homology, the spaces will always intersect in the basepoint). One way to do this would be to add a disjoint basepoint to $X \cup Y$ and claim it is part of both $X$ and $Y$. Then we see our sequence is exact (in fact it is the same as the unreduced Mayer-Vietoris). This is hinting at the fact that you can define unreduced homology from reduced homology.

Comment: @ConnorMalin I would argue that the 'correct' definition of $\widetilde H_\ast(X)$ is as the kernel of the map $H_\ast(X)\rightarrow H_\ast(\ast)$ induced by the unique map $X\rightarrow\ast$ (of course this map does not split naturally if you work with unpointed spaces, and may not even split at all. In the case that $X$ is pointed, then our two definitions agree.). I would go as far to suggest that the mistake some texts make is to introduce relative groups $H_\ast(X,A)$ at all.

Comment: @Tyrone The only result I can recall that needs to be stated in reduced homology and does not have an immediately obvious interpretation in terms of homology rel the basepoint, is Alexander duality. Even then, it can be interpretted in terms of homology rel the basepoint, and this actually is the more geometrically correct way. I have been on the lookout for more, so I'd love to know some.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Functorality. An unpointed map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ induces a map $f_*:\widetilde H_nX\rightarrow\widetilde H_nY$ (my definition) but no map $H_n(X,x_0)\rightarrow H_n(Y,y_0)$ unless $f(x_0)=y_0$. Moreover, even if this holds, then the induced map $f_*$ depends on $f$ and not on its unpointed homotopy class. Thus you don't get a functor from the homotopy category *unpointed spaces* to graded abelian groups if you use the relative version.

Comment: I do certainly agree with you that reduced homology is generally more useful for pointed spaces, and I have no real objection to your preferred definition in that context.

Comment: Alternatively, you have omitted the next term in your exact sequence: $\tilde{H}_{-1}(\emptyset) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: In Spanier's book, he says that the empty space has no reduced singular homology because the homology group of the empty space is 0 hence it does not admit an augmentation to $\mathbb{Z}$ which is epimorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you pass to reduced homology before forming $H_0X\oplus H_0Y$. I'll reference Hatcher's statement and proof (pg 149) in the context of singular homology, since it is particularly lucid. Observe that the existence of the Mayer-Vietor sequence is established by Hatcher by forming the short exact sequence of chain complexes

$$0\rightarrow C_*(X\cap Y)\rightarrow C_*(X)\oplus C_*(Y)\rightarrow C_*(X\cup Y)\rightarrow 0\qquad (\ast)$$

and computing the resulting long-exact sequence of homology groups. The result is the long exact sequence

$$\dots\rightarrow H_n(X\cap Y)\rightarrow H_n(X)\oplus H_n(Y)\rightarrow H_n(X\cup Y)\rightarrow H_{n-1}(X\cap Y)\rightarrow\dots$$

in *unreduced* homology, which ends

$$\dots\rightarrow H_0(X\cap Y)\rightarrow H_0(X)\oplus H_0(Y)\rightarrow H_0(X\cup Y)\rightarrow 0$$

If you prefer to work with *reduced* homology then you have to use the reduced homology of the sequence labelled $(\ast)$. i.e. you have to treat $C_*(X)\oplus C_*(Y)$ as one object.

Recall that in the singular context, the reduced homology $\widetilde H_n(K)$ is defined (pg 110) to be the $n^{th}$ homology group of the augemented chain complex

$$\dots\rightarrow C_n(K)\rightarrow C_{n-1}(K)\rightarrow\dots\rightarrow C_1(K)\rightarrow C_0(K)\xrightarrow\epsilon \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$$

Thus the correct way to take the reduced homology of the chain complex $C_\ast(X)\oplus C_*(Y)$ is to take the homology of the chain complex ending

$$\dots\rightarrow C_1(X)\oplus C_1(Y)\rightarrow C_0(X)\oplus C_0(Y)\xrightarrow{\epsilon\oplus\epsilon}\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow0$$

Now the chain complex $(\ast)$ ends in degree $-1$ as

$$0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow0.$$

For example, in the example you create you find exactness of

$$0\rightarrow \widetilde H_0(X)\oplus\widetilde H_0(Y)\rightarrow\widetilde H_0(X\sqcup Y)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$$

where of course $\widetilde H_0(X)\oplus\widetilde H_0(Y)=0$.

This is discussed by hatcher on pg 150. You can check that you get the correct answer when using this correct definition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate approach. I find that exercise 38 on p. 159 of Hatcher is a good way to derive the Mayer-Vietoris sequence: there is a commutative diagram
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
\to & H_{n+1}(X, X \cap Y) & \to & H_n (X \cap Y) & \to & H_n(X) & \to & H_n(X, X \cap Y) & \to \\
 & \downarrow^\cong & & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow^\cong \\
\to & H_{n+1}(X \cup Y, Y) & \to & H_n (Y) & \to & H_n(X \cup Y) & \to & H_n(X \cup Y, Y) & \to
\end{array}
$$
Because of the isomorphisms at the end, a diagram chase (this is Hatcher's exercise 38) produces the Mayer-Vietoris sequence.

Since you also have a commutative diagram with reduced homology, you also get a Mayer-Vietoris sequence there, but as always with reduced homology, you have to be careful with empty sets: the reduced homology of the empty set is $H_q(\emptyset) = 0$ if $q \geq 0$ but $H_{-1}(\emptyset) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ — this is also the same as the augmented chain complex for the empty set. The tail end of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence is
$$
\to \widetilde{H}_0(X \cap Y) \to \widetilde{H}_0(X) \oplus \widetilde{H}_0(Y) \to \widetilde{H}_0(X \cup Y) \to \widetilde{H}_{-1}(X \cap Y) \to
$$
so the $(-1)$-dimensional homology of the empty set can enter into play.